# Purpose of try! in Swift

Tags: swift

I am confused as what exactly is the purpose of try!. The documentation says that you can use try! to call methods that can throw exception but try! is used as a promise from the caller that it will not throw an exception or the developer is not interested in the result of the exception.

So, if the developer is not interested in catching that exception then why even throw the exception from the method in the first case.

```
func foo() throws {
 }

try! foo() 

Why not: 

func foo() {
}

foo()
```

Comment: the implementation of the function which throws the exception is not necessarily written by the same developer who will call the function..so i can call a function which i am not interested in its exception but this does't eliminate the necessity to throw exception in the called function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
struct Error:ErrorType{}
// function is defined somewhere
// i know just the declaration
//
// func foo(i:Int!) throws -> Void
//

func foo(i: Int!) throws {
    if i == nil {
        throw Error()
    }
}

// i am sure the call is 'safe'
// this simplifies my code
try! foo(2)

//foo(2)  // error: call can throw but is not marked with 'try'

let str = "2,2" // mimic result of some operation
do {
    // i am not sure if str represents an Int
    try foo(Int(str))
} catch {
    print("error")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A function could throw errors if it gets illegal parameters. However, if this function is used with an UI that allows only the input of legal parameters, then you can call this function with `try!`, because you are sure that the exception is never thrown.

I read a book on Swift that says you can use `try!` in the early stages of development, because the app will crash if an error is thrown, so a developer or tester cannot overlook this error. However, I wouldn't use this, because it could be forgotten to remove a `try!` before the code goes into production.